# Replace values in text file for one batch with AWK and increment subsequent value from last one

Tags: bash, shell, awk, replace

I have the following in a text file called data.txt

```
&st=1000&type=rec&uniId=5800000000&acceptCode=1000&drainNel=supp&
&st=1100&type=rec&uniId=5800000000&acceptCode=1000&drainNel=supp&
&st=4100&type=rec&uniId=6500000000&acceptCode=4100&drainNel=ured&
&st=4200&type=rec&uniId=6500000000&acceptCode=4100&drainNel=iris&
&st=4300&type=rec&uniId=6500000000&acceptCode=4100&drainNel=iris&
&st=8300&type=rec&uniId=7700000000&acceptCode=8300&drainNel=teef&
```

1) Script will take an input argument in the form of a number, e.g: **979035210000000098**

2) I want to replace all the text value for `uniId=xxxxxxxxxx` with the given long number passed in the argument to script. **IMPORTANT: if uniID is same, it will replace same value for all of them. (In this case, first two lines are same, then next three lines are same, then last one is same) For the next batch, it will replace + increment (5,000,000,000) from last one**

Ignore all other fields and they should not be modified.

So essentially doing this:

```
./script.sh 979035210000000098
```

.. still confused? Well, the final result could be this:

```
&st=1000&type=rec&uniId=979035210000000098&acceptCode=1000&drainNel=supp&
&st=1100&type=rec&uniId=979035210000000098&acceptCode=1000&drainNel=supp&
&st=4100&type=rec&uniId=979035215000000098&acceptCode=4100&drainNel=ured&
&st=4200&type=rec&uniId=979035215000000098&acceptCode=4100&drainNel=iris&
&st=4300&type=rec&uniId=979035215000000098&acceptCode=4100&drainNel=iris&
&st=8300&type=rec&uniId=979035220000000098&acceptCode=8300&drainNel=teef&
```

This ^ should be REPLACED and applied to tempfile datanew.txt - not just print on screen.

An AWK script exists which does replacement for `&st=xxx` and for `&acceptCode=xxx` but perhaps I can reuse, not able to get it working as I expect?

```
# $./script.sh [STARTCOUNT] < data.txt > datanew.txt
# $ mv -f datanew.txt data.txt
awk  -F '&' -v "cnt=${1:-10000}" -v 'OFS=&' \
   'NR == 1 { ac = cnt; uni = $4; }
    NR > 1 && $4 == uni { cnt += 100 }
    $4 != uni { cnt += 5000000000; ac = cnt; uni = $4 }
    { $2 = "st=" cnt; $5 = "acceptCode=" ac; print }'
```

Comment: So each time `acceptCode` changes you want to increment `uniId` ?

Comment: each time uniId changes... ignore all fields. (But yes, I guess we can even look at acceptCode changing as it will change too with uniId)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `gnu awk` you may use this:

```
awk -M -i inplace -v num=979035210000000098 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="&"}
!seen[$4]++{p = (NR>1 ? p+5000000000 : num)} {$4="uniId=" p} 1' file
```

```
&st=1000&type=rec&uniId=979035210000000098&acceptCode=1000&drainNel=supp&
&st=1100&type=rec&uniId=979035210000000098&acceptCode=1000&drainNel=supp&
&st=4100&type=rec&uniId=979035215000000098&acceptCode=4100&drainNel=ured&
&st=4200&type=rec&uniId=979035215000000098&acceptCode=4100&drainNel=iris&
&st=4300&type=rec&uniId=979035215000000098&acceptCode=4100&drainNel=iris&
&st=8300&type=rec&uniId=979035220000000098&acceptCode=8300&drainNel=teef&
```

Options `-M` or `--bignum` forces arbitrary precision arithmetic on numbers in `gnu awk`.